# How can we find a subspace from the affine subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra

The affine subspace is a translation of a unique subspace, that is if $A$ is and affine subspace then 
\begin{equation*}
A=S+a
\end{equation*}
where $S$ is a unique subspace and $a$ is some vector in $A$. Now to get the subspace $S$ from $A$ is just to do the subtraction
\begin{equation*}
S=A-a
\end{equation*}
Untill now it is understood . My question is how can we do that? For instance, if we have the following concrete example?

Example: Assume $L$ is a line in $\mathbb{R}^3$ defined by the following two equation
\begin{equation*}
4x+7y=46
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
y+z=9
\end{equation*}
or alternatively, we can defined $L$ by the parametric equation
\begin{equation*}
L=(1,6,3)+t(7,-4,4)
\end{equation*}
Can any one show to me can me find the subspace that has been translated by some vector to get this line (affine subspace)?
Any help will be really appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Pick a point of $L$, such as $(1, 6, 3)$. Subtract that from every point of $L$. You get a new line,

$$
L' = \{ t(7, -4, 4) : t \in \mathbb R \},
$$
which is your subspace $S$.

Alternatively, for your line-equation example, you can pick $z = 0,$ so $y = 9$, so $4x = 46-63 = 17$, so $x = 17/4$, and subtract that from every point of the intersection. Or you  can realize that if you translate the defining planes, the new intersection line will be parallel to the old one, and so you can replace your defining equations by 
$$
4x + 7y = 0 \\
y + z = 0
$$
to define the subspace $S$.

Comment: Thanks John, but I already did exactly the same, and when I plotted the two lines (one for the affine subspace and another one for subspace) using Maple I got two intersected lines which they supposed to be parallel so I do not why? is there any thing wrong here?

Comment: Yes. Your Maple plot or Maple code is wrong. For you are suggesting that you have lines $L$ (the affine subsapce that is the intersection of $4x + 7y = 46$ and $y+z = 9$) and $L'$ (parallel vector subspace that is the intersection of $4x +7y = 0$ and $y + z = 0$) and that they intersect at a point $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$. That point must have $y_0 + z_0 = 9$ to be on the first line, and $y_0 + z_0 = 0$ to be on the second line. That makes $0 = 9$, which is impossible in $\mathbb R$.